# iPhone/Obj-C - Archiving object causes lag

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I have a table view, and when I delete a cell I am removing an item from an NSMutableArray, archiving that array, and removing the cell.

However, when I do this, it is causing the delete button to lag after I click it.  Is there any way to fix this?

```
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        int row = [indexPath row]; 
        [savedGames removeObjectAtIndex:row]; 
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        //this line causing lag
        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:savedGames toFile:[self dataFilePath]];
    }
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you know the answer already -- don't archive everything on every delete.  This can be done a number of ways -- archiving only pieces at a time, delayed archiving (periodically/when quitting/other policies), or making your custom archiving code considerably faster, which I doubt would even help that much in the scheme of things.  I've *heard* that MAKeyedArchiver was faster than NSKeyedArchiver, but I believe this was some time ago, and designed for the mac+potentially platform specific (on the bright side it was intended as a drop in replacement for the NSKeyedArchiver API of the time, so it should be little integration time if you choose to use it).